# how to pass a variable through read in bash

Tags: bash, shell, variables, mkdir

I'm trying to make a script which asks for a directory path and then creates that directory. I'd like to be able to pass variables to the read builtin so pathnames so I don't have to type out full paths:

```
function make_dir {
echo "What is the path of the directory to be created?"
read directory
mkdir "$directory"
}
```

so I'd type:

```
make_dir
What is the path of the directory to be created?
$HOME/temp_dir
mkdir: cannot create directory `$HOME/temp_dir': No such file or directory
```

So I'd like to have `$HOME` expanded into `/home/user/` and the script to make the directory `/home/user/temp_dir`, but I can't seem to get the expansion to work.

If I modify the `make_dir` function to `show_dir` below

```
function show_dir {
echo "What is the path of the directory to be created?"
read directory
echo "The directory is $directory"
}
```

and I type `$HOME/temp_dir` and get the following:

```
make_dir
What is the path of the directory to be created?
$HOME/temp_dir
The directory is $HOME/temp_dir
```

with no expansion. Any ideas on how to get this to work?

Comment: The only answer is `eval` which is not a good solution. With `read -e` tab completion might expand it for you and any readline bindings that expand variables (like `meta-ctrl-e` or `esc ctrl-e`) will expand it before you hit enter.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, adding `eval` in front of `mkdir "$directoy"` seems to work, can you help me understand why this is not a good solution?

Comment: there is a good explanation here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17529220/why-should-eval-be-avoided-in-bash-and-what-should-i-use-instead

Comment: Also http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/048

Comment: @BrianAlbertMonroe apart from using eval as Etan mentioned, you'd use mkdir -p as well. OR mkdir won't work if a folder doesn't already exist for any of the sub path folders.

Comment: Great stuff, always learning. Can't I get around this issue by putting `newdir=$(eval echo "$directory")` after the `read directory` line and chage `mkdir "$directory"` to `mkdir "$newdir"`? If some evil command was passed into `read` wouldn't `echo` just pass the entered command as text into the variable `newdir` without executing it?

Comment: @BrianAlbertMonroe The problem is if `$directory` expands to something like `some string; rm -rf /*`. `eval` then gets the string `echo some string; rm -rf /*` to execute.

Answer (score 1):

It's a little cumbersome, but one option is to use  the `-e` flag to tell `read` to use Readline to get the input, then use Readline to expand the line after typing it, but before hitting Enter.

```
$ read -e directory
$HOME/dir
```

Now type <kbd>Meta</kbd>-<kbd>Control</kbd>-<kbd>e</kbd>, and Readline will expand the input just as if it were being processed prior to execution as a shell command. (Note that the Meta key is probably Alt or Esc, depending on your terminal setup.)

Comment: Better than having an `eval` disaster I suppose, but as you say it's cumbersome and it won't expand `~` into `/home/user`.

Comment: It should expand `~`.

Comment: There is a program out there that takes a string and outputs the string that results from substitution the value of any *environment* variables in the input, but for the life of me I can't remember what it is called.

Comment: Strange, I tried again and it worked. Must've hit a wrong key. That program would be perfect, should you remember please post it. Until then I think I'm just going to type full paths for this particular function.

Answer (score 1):

You are actually making things more difficult by attempting to get the directory with `read`. Unless you have an absolute requirement to use `read`, you are better off passing the directory to your function `as an argument`. For example:

```
function make_dir {
    [ -n "$1" ] || {
        printf "\n usage: make_dir <path_to_create>\n\n"
        return 1
    }
    mkdir -p "$1" || {
        printf "\n error: unable to create '$1', check permissions\n\n"
    }
}
```

**example:**

```
$ function make_dir {
>     [ -n "$1" ] || {
>         printf "\n usage: make_dir <path_to_create>\n\n"
>         return 1
>     }
>     mkdir -p "$1" || {
>         printf "\n error: unable to create '$1', check permissions\n\n"
>     }
> }

$ make_dir $HOME/temp_dir

$ ls -al temp_dir
total 8
drwxr-xr-x  2 david david 4096 Nov 26 15:34 .
drwxr-xr-x 76 david david 4096 Nov 26 15:34 ..

$ make_dir

usage: make_dir <path_to_create>
```

When you pass the directory to your function `as an argument` instead of using `read`, you can easily adjust your function to `take/create multiple directories` as well:

```
function make_dir {
    [ -n "$1" ] || {
        printf "\n usage: make_dir <path_to_create> [path2, ..]\n\n"
        return 1
    }
    for i in "$@" ; do
        mkdir -p "$i" || {
            printf "\n error: unable to create '$i', check permissions\n\n"
        }
    done
}
```

**example:**

```
$ make_dir temp_dir_{1..3}
$ ls -1d temp_*
temp_dir_1
temp_dir_2
temp_dir_3
```

Comment: Using arguments to a function doesn't help my situation. The function is called in a larger script which asks the user for a path to be created, thus the need for `read`.

Comment: Fair enough, I was just working from your example. But in your larger context, `read` is fine.

Answer (score 0):

change the following line:

```
mkdir "$directory"
```

with

```
eval mkdir -p "$directory"
```

Comment: Very dangerous; this allows a malicious user to craft a "directory name" that contains an arbitrary command line, and it will execute. Verification with `[[ -d $directory ]] && eval mkdir -p "$directory"` is a little better, but I would still recommend against using `eval` here.